How to send pdf attachment file as a buffer or stream?
I'm trying to send a pdf attachment file from a form directly to an email
I'm runinng nodemailer on nextjs 14 server side
according to nodemailer doc the content property can be any of this types String, Buffer or a Stream.
I tried string option and it works (✅) the other 2 option I stuck on it (❌)
I tried another option using path property rather than content property and it works (✅) which I'm not looking for as answer because I think if it is possible to buffer or stream the pdf from the Form this will be a direct and one trip easer than uploading pdf to remote storage and getting URL path to pass it in path property .
the last tries steps to convert pdf to a buffer is :

when the user select his pdf I receive it as a File


then I submit it :


"use server";
import { mailOptions, transporter } from "../config/nodemailer";
interface EmailInputes {
  name: string;
  file: File | null;
}

export async function submittingEmail({ name, file }: EmailInputes) {

  if (!file) return;

  // --- her I'm trying to converting file to buffer ---
  const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
  const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);

  await transporter.sendMail({
    ...mailOptions,
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: "test.pdf",
        content: fileBuffer,
      },
    ],
    subject: `Testing Attachments`,
    text: "this a text",
    html: `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <body style="direction:rtl">
          <h1 style="color:darkgreen; text-align: center;margin:0;font-size:24px">Testing Attachments</h1>
          <p>contact visitor name is : ${name}</p>
      </body>
      </html>
      `,
  });
}

when I submit like this way I receive an error and nothing sent


@KJ I read it before and this is exactly what I'm trying to do but not working for me for some reason. the answer also focus on fetching the file while I'm not doing fetch (the file is located on user device locally)
